# Mulit jQuery UI Datepickers with different settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to show more than one datepicker with different settings on one page using [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

```
//Datepicker
$("input.date-picker").datepicker({ 
});

// Additional settings
$("input.date-picker.multi-calendars").datepicker({
   numberOfMonths: 3
});
```

"//Additional settings" simply gets ignored and only the "//Datepicker" get applied despite setting the datepicker to show 3 months when it has the class `.multi-calendars`.

After hours of digging onto this, I found one solution. Remove the class `hasDatepicker` from the UI library `markerClassName: "hasDatepicker"`

This fixed the problem, however, my month and year dropdown menus does not work anymore. When I click on the dropdown to pick a date or a year the whole datepicker just closes!

So I looked into a way to fix this but to no avail.

Is the UI datepicker really that limited? or its just me missing something?

Here is a live preview: http://loai.directory/test/test - its both inputs that has the label "Date picker".

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle to innustrate this instread of your website that will no longer exists in few hours? :-) Did you tried to reverse, put the $("input.date-picker.multi-calendars") before $("input.date-picker") ?

Comment: I have created one here: http://jsfiddle.net/1mo4x9f9/ - the datepicker calls are at the very bottom of the JS window.

Comment: @clement huh!!!! it fixed it :'( :'( man I spent all morning trying to get it to work! Why does it work this one? :/ - the only thing is - what If I needed to apply a call for a custom calendar somewhere on the website pages... it will be positioned under them, so it is not that reliable is it?

Comment: glad to help. You always have to load jquery UI components at the end of the html, after the rest. I don't know how you work, you want to put those script on every page? even if there is no datepicker? I will do a response that you can accept if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the second selector first.

DatePicker doesn't allow you to apply it twice on the same element, so you have to put specific datepicker selector first then more general ones that applies datepicker on other dp elements:

```
// Additional settings
$("input.date-picker.multi-calendars").datepicker({
   numberOfMonths: 3
});

//Datepicker
$("input.date-picker").datepicker({ 
});
```

Comment: This fixed it, however, the input.date-picker is some sort of a default settings to all calendars unless they have additional settings just like the example I gave shows. 

What happens if on a specific page I want to apply a specific setting for a datapicker? Obviously then I will need to add it within <script> at the very end - which is after all scripts and libraries are called - so that specific calendar won't work then, will it?

Comment: if you want to apply specific rule to specific datepicker, you have to do it before the latest $("input.date-picker") that applies default datepicker. If you want to control every datepicker, maybe that you can use $("input.date-picker.default"") selector and add this class to all default datepickers. With that trick, it doesn't matter the order... Once again I don't know how about your app structure or even framework, but I personaly use a script for global JS at the very end of the page, and if there is specific JS for one specific page, it is applied before the global one, ever.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will just need to apply an extra class ehh.

Comment: would you please be able to help me with this as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121584/validate-chosen-multi-selection-with-parsley-js